# Is "違和感を感じる" really redundant?

Tags: meaning, words, nuances

> 違和感を感じる

Most Japanese say that this phrase is redundant because 感 and 感じる have the same meaning, and that *違和感を覚える* is correct.
I have two questions here.

1. **Why using 覚える is correct?**

As far as I know, 感じる and 覚える here mean the same(to feel), so I think both of them are correct or incorrect. Are there any difference I do not know?

2. **Is *違和感を感じる* really wrong?**

I think *違和感を感じる* is a right expression. It is because 違和感 does not indicate that I *感じる*, and 感じる does not mean to feel *違和感*. I have heard *違和感を感じる* said many times so I believe that some think it is natural. So Is it really redundant?

Comment: I think some Japanese think so but some Japanese don't think so. I think it isn't unnatural. This is interesting link. https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12102020797

Comment: I think it's probably a matter of prescription. That is, this is a phrase that native speakers will produce naturally (it has hundreds of thousands of hits on the Web), but some people think it's ugly or sounds wrong, so they reject it. Think "grammar peeves", like English people who reject perfectly natural split infinitives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) 違和感を感じる
>   2) 違和感を覚える

- I think both phrases are correct.
- The phrase 1) is as much frequently used as twice of 2) when I searched for the frequency of their use on the Internet.
- Though people use 1) more frequently than 2), they feel 1) seems redundant because 1) has two "**感**"s, so if you want to use 1) confidently, you have to know 1) is not redundant reffering the answer in the [link](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12102020797) shown by Yuuichi Tam.

The following Japanese is what the answer tells roughly as a whole, while my poor interpretation in English for it is only for your immediate convenience:

> 「馬から落馬」は「落馬」自体に「馬から」という意味が含まれているため、更に「馬から」をつけると二重表現になるが、「違和感を感じる」に関しては、「違和感」には「感じる」という意味はなく、「違和感」全体で初めて一つの「感じ」を表す名詞になるから「違和感を感じる」は冗長ではない。更に、「違和感を感じる」に冗長な表現が含まれていないことは、「違和感」から「感」を除いた「違和を感じる」が意味をなさないことからもわかる。
>
> As for "**馬から落馬**", "落馬" has a meaning "to fall from a horse" in itself, so if you add "馬から *from a horse*" to "落馬", the whole phrase "馬から落馬" becomes a redundant expression. On the other hand, as for "**違和感を感じる**", it is not redundant because "違和感 *a sense of discomfort, sense of incongruity/incompatibility* or *unpleasant sensation*" has no meaning of "to feel" and "違和" becomes a noun with "感" that represents a kind of "senses or sensations" for the first time in "違和感" as a whole. And more, the fact that **redundant expressions** are not included in "違和感を感じる" can be understood from the fact that "感" in "違和感" is inevitable because "違和を感じる" does not make sense.

- In my opinion, "I feel the sense of discomfort *mentally* in "違和感を覚える" while I feel it more *physically* in "違和感を感じる" because of the difference of the basic meanings of the two *kanji*s in 覚える and 感じる.
- Although the frequency of use written above about the both expressions is about what are written in the contents on the Internet, I think 違和感を感じる is much more frequently used than the other in conversations. The reason for this is that in the conversation it is difficult to know in a short time whether the *kanji* "感" is used twice and also difficult to concern whether it is redundant or not.
- The verb "覚える" is commonly used in the sense of "to memorize something", but "覚える" in "違和感を覚える" has a meaning similar to "感じる *feel*".
  This usage of "覚える" is often used by writers in the novels, but usually not used by common people so much. Therefore, when an ordinary person uses "違和感を覚える", it sounds somewhat formal and also sounds solemn, grave, majestic or magnificent.
- For the above reason, I recommend you not to use "違和感を覚える" so much in usual conversations. Also, it is better not to use "違和感を感じる" in writing even it is grammatically correct, and even if you can explain the reason clearly, because the *kanji* "感"s remain twice in one written sentence.
  Instead of these expressions, although not having exactly the same meaning, I would show you the phrase "違和感がある" can be used with confidence.
- There is a phrase "異和感{いわかん}を感じる" which has the same sound and similar meaning to "違和感を感じる". "異和" of "異和感を感じる" is medical terms having a meaning relating to "異物 *foreign body* or *object*" such as a tumor in a throat. In general, "違和感を感じる" is used for the matter/event outside yourself, while "異和感を感じる" is used for something within or about your body.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to mackygoo's comments, if you don't want to say 「違和感を覚える」 -- (be caused to) "remember" (a feeling of) discomfort] -- 「違和感がある・ない」 is available.

Don't try too hard to map English vocabulary and grammar directly to the Japanese.